# How to reference control characters (eg CRLF) in SAS Macro Variable

Tags: sas

I need to search for control characters (eg LF) within a macro variable.

The datastep below proves that the control characters are there. My question is - how do I test for this within a macro function?

```
data _null_;
  length start mactest  $10;
  start='blah' !! '0A'x !! 'blah';
  call symputx('mactest',start);
  mactest=symget('mactest');
  finish1=find(start,'0A'x);
  finish2=find(start,byte(10));
  finish3=find(start,'
');
put finish1= finish2= finish3=;
run;

%put whereisit? %sysfunc(find(&mactest,'0A'x));
%put no, really? %sysfunc(find(&mactest,%sysfunc(byte(10))));
%put do I really need to do this? %sysfunc(find(&mactest,%str(
)));
```

[image: log result]

^^ I was able to get a result by literally adding a carriage return from my keyboard, but super strange that this was different depending on whether it was entered to data step or macro (I'm using macbook, studio, 9.4, firefox).

**EDIT** - per feedback from @FriedEgg and @Stu it's possible to search using `qsysfunc()` however this breaks when the macro variable contains a space - eg:

```
data _null_;
  length lf $10;
  lf='bl ah' !! '0A'x !! 'blah';
  call symputx('lf',lf);
run;
/* returns 3 but should return 6 */
%put lf=%sysfunc(find(&lf,%qsysfunc(inputc(0A,$hex.))));
```

Comment: %qsysfunc(byte(10))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is to blame, once the strings `mactest` or `lf` are fed into `find` the 0 carriage return or line feed or similar are just converted to spaces `\x20` which is why you are seeing these results.  Best solution I can think of is to bring the problem as far away from SAS macro BS as possible...

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.func.macro;
  function symgetz(mvar $) $;
      dsid = open('sashelp.vmacro(where=(name='!!quote(upcase(strip(mvar)))!!'))');
        rc = fetch(dsid);
        return (getvarc(dsid, varnum(dsid, 'value')));
  endsub;

  function prxmatchz(prx $,mvar $);
      return (prxmatch(prx,symgetz(mvar)));
  endsub;
quit;

options cmplib=work.func;

data _null_;
  test='bl ah' !! '0A'x !! 'blah';
  call symput('test',test);
run;

%put cr=%sysfunc(prxmatchz(/\x0A/,test));
```

Comment: Nice!  Is the file handle closed automatically?

Comment: should probably explicitly close it, but I haven't encountered an issue.  The symgetz function itself may not be necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to hex with `inputc`, and enclose that with `%qsysfunc` rather than `%sysfunc` since a carriage return is a special character that will be ignored by the macro compiler.

```
%put hereitis! %sysfunc(find(&mactest,%qsysfunc(inputc(0A, $hex.) ) ) );
```

Comment: this works but only if there are no spaces preceding the character in the string.